# In Microsoft Word, why does selecting a lot of text set the font style dropdown to blank?

Tags: ms-word

I am working with Word 365, but I have seen this in previous versions.

Say you want to change the font and size of a section of text. In the Home Ribbon, under Font, you have a drop-down with the Font Family (say, Arial) and one with the size (12). Now, if I just grab a few paragraphs, it will show me the current family and size, if everything is the same. But if you grab the whole document, the dropdowns turn blank.

I understand, if I have conflicting sizes in my selection, say Arial 10 and Arial 12, then size will be blank. But once I pick 12, it changes the size of my entire selection to 12. But if I select it AGAIN, and everything I selected is Arial 12, the dropdown is still blank.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new table with at least 15 rows.
2. Select the first few rows, you will see the family and size listed in the dropdowns.
3. Select 13 rows. The dropdowns are blank, EVEN THOUGH every single row is the same font family and size.

Is there any way to adjust this behavior?

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others

Comment: When you do post elsewhere, I would suggest giving the volunteers you want to help you a link to a sample document with the problem. Here is why and how: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258